# how to override the specific style of spans in a div [span in a span ] using css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

1. if we are having div and having no of spans i.e span in a span and every span has a style of color how to override the specific style[color] using css or jquery.. .  please help me

Comment: Try posting a fiddle. Here is one to get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/Ca7tL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<div><span style="color:red;">red <span style="color:blue;">blue</span></span></div>
```

If so, you can use !important to change their color:

```
div span {color: green !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `.css()` function 
example `$("span").css("color","red");`

or create a separate css class and use `.addClass()` for the spans